# Jenkins: fastlane fails in cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, jenkins, cocoapods, fastlane

I've been struggling to make cocoapods working in fastlane/jenkins.
Here is the console output from Jenkins:

```
[12:40:31]: [32m--- Step: cocoapods ---[0m
[12:40:31]: [32m-----------------------[0m
[12:40:31]: [36m$ bundle exec pod install[0m
+------------------+------+
|      [33mLane Context[0m       |
+------------------+------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios  |
| PLATFORM_NAME    |      |
| LANE_NAME        | beta |
+------------------+------+
[12:40:31]: [31mNo such file or directory - bundle[0m

+------+-----------------------+-------------+
|              [32mfastlane summary[0m              |
+------+-----------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                | Time (in s) |
+------+-----------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform      | 0           |
| 2    | clean_build_artifacts | 0           |
|    | [31mcocoapods[0m             | 0           |
+------+-----------------------+-------------+

[12:40:31]: [31mfastlane finished with errors[0m

[12:40:31]: [33mError accessing file, this might be due to fastlane's directory handling[0m
[12:40:31]: [33mCheck out https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#directory-behavior for more details[0m
```

Everything just worked like a charm before adding `cocoapods` action in the lane of the Fastfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up disabling bundle in `cocoapods` action like below.

```
cocoapods(use_bundle_exec: false)
```

Spent a lot of hours to discover it though. Hope it can help others later on.

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, the error is in the console log:

> No such file or directory - bundle

The `cocoapods` action is built off of the base `Fastlane::Action` class. I dug in and found that *if* you have a [Gemfile](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/294b9adcbec76debe56fd0e8b289791bb558aa77/fastlane/lib/fastlane/action.rb#L138), fastlane believes that it can use the `bundle` method (from the `bundler` gem) to run a faster and more correct `bundle exec pod install`.

If you are not using `bundler` to run exact versions of the Ruby gems you are using, I would remove the Gemfile as it is a useless stub.

However, I strongly recommend that you use `bundler` to make sure that you are always using the exact versions of Ruby gems that you use to develop your fastlane code. It is faster too. [Read more](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile).

Comment: But other commands like `fastlane beta` are already using `bundle` so `bundle exec fastlane beta`

Comment: Is `beta` a lane that you created? If so, it will be up to your code to use it or not. If you are not using the Gemfile, try removing it and remove the parameter from your call to `cocoapods`